# PhpStorm, Laravel and autocompletition

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a method `run()` in `TreeGen` class:

```
class TreeGen implements TreeGenerable{

 public function run()
 {
     ...
     $this->pushEmptyGroupsToTree($numFighters);
     ...
 }
}
```

Thing is `$this` could be one of the 4 Subclasses of tree gen, and all those method implement different versions of `pushEmptyGroupsToTree`.

But PhpStorm is only looking for `pushEmptyGroupsToTree` in TreeGen class and off course, I don't have it defined in the super class, so it doesn't detect it.

Is there a way to make him recognize subclass methods?

Comment: Upcoming (2017.2) version would include improved child->parent relation detection. You can check it in latest EAP: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDE behaves correctly. You either need to declare this class abstract, or declare abstract method here or in superclass.

**UPDATE**

Method `run` of `TreeGen` could be called from instance of `Treegen`

```
$treeGen = new TreeGen;
$treeGen->run();
```

and that will cause **Call to undefined method** error.

If `TreeGen` is not supposed to be called directly it should be abstract.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want `TreeGreen` to be used directly, declare it abstract as such:

```
abstract class TreeGen implements TreeGenerable {
// ...
```

If you need the child classes to have that method declared, declare it as abstract in your superclass:

```
abstract class TreeGen implements TreeGenerable
{
    // ...
    abstract public function pushEmptyGroupsToTree($numFighters);
}
```

Now you cant extend `TreeGen` without implementing `pushEmptyGroupsToTree` as well

Answer (score 0):

For this case you must use [PHPDoc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/phpdoc-comments.html) and [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

And don`t forget about:

```
  ide-helper:generate  Generate a new IDE Helper file.
  ide-helper:meta      Generate metadata for PhpStorm
  ide-helper:models    Generate autocompletion for models
```